# Splunk : Extracting the elements from JSON structure as separate fields

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

In Splunk, I'm trying to extract the key value pairs inside that "tags" element of the JSON structure so each one of the become a separate column so I can search through them.
for example :

```
| spath data | rename data.tags.EmailAddress AS Email
```

This does not help though and Email field comes as empty.I'm trying to do this for all the tags. Any thoughts/pointers?

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-10-26T18:23:05.180707Z",
    "data": {
        "tags": [
            {
                "key": "Email",
                "value": "john.doe@example.com"
            },
            {
                "key": "ProjectCode",
                "value": "ABCD"
            },
            {
                "key": "Owner",
                "value": "John Doe"
            }
        ]
    },
    "field1": "random1",
    "field2": "random2"
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think does what you want:

```
 | spath data.tags{}
 | mvexpand data.tags{}
 | spath input=data.tags{}
 | table key value
 | transpose header_field=key
 | fields - column
```

How it works:

`| spath data.tags{}` takes the json and creates a multi value field that contains each item in the tags array

`| mvexpand data.tags{}` splits the multi value field into individual events - each one contains one of the items in the tags array

`| spath input=data.tags{}` takes the json in each event and makes a field for each KVP in that item (`key` and `value` in this case)

`| table key value` limits further commands to these two fields

`| transpose header_field=key` makes a field for each value of the `key` field (including one for the field named `column`)`

`| fields - column` removes the `column` field from the output

Here is a fully runnable example:

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="
{
  \"timestamp\": \"2021-10-26T18:23:05.180707Z\",
  \"data\": {
    \"tags\": [
      {\"key\": \"Email\", \"value\": \"john.doe@example.com\"},
      {\"key\": \"ProjectCode\", \"value\": \"ABCD\"},
      {\"key\": \"Owner\", \"value\": \"John Doe\"}
    ]
  },
  \"field1\": \"random1\",
  \"field2\": \"random2\"
}
"
| spath data.tags{}
| mvexpand data.tags{}
| spath input=data.tags{}
| table key value
| transpose header_field=key
```

It creates this output:

```
+----------------------+-------------+----------+
| Email                | ProjectCode | Owner    |
+----------------------+-------------+----------+
| john.doe@example.com | ABCD        | John Doe |
+----------------------+-------------+----------+
```